# App installation error : Flutter ADB exited

Tags: flutter

I m getting below error after successful build of every flutter app .
Plz share the way to resolve it
"Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...                 7.0s
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\projectss\downloader\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user]
Error launching application on M2006C3MII."

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Do check that install via usb option is selected on your developer option.

if it still not works, then revoke usb authorisations unplug your device and plug it..and select MTP or file transfer from charging tray this one works for me

Answer (score 0):

Clear Your mobile storage and try reinstalling it again. flutter apps take a lot of storage when building .
I recommend at least 1GB of free space before installing the app